# Static pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am getting a problem with my homework and I was wondering if you could help me out. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRSIZE 1000

int main(){
    f1();
    f2();
    f3();
    return 0;
}

void f1(){
    static int n;
    n++;
    char arr[ARRSIZE];
    static long int *addr=arr;
    printf("Call #%d at %d\n",n,addr);

    if(n<10)
        f1();
}

void f2(){

}

void f3(){

}
```

and here is the error:

```
error: initializer element is not constant
```

Thank you.

Comment: The error message is clear: the initialize of a static variable has to be a constant expression. The address of a local variable is not a constant, since it depends on where the function is called from.

Comment: Local variables are destroyed when the function returns. It doesn't make sense to have a static pointer to something that no longer exists.

Comment: If you make `arr` a global variable it will work.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why does `addr` need to be static?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so I can subtract the address of the pointer with the address of what it used to be. Taken right from the directions of my homework:\

Comment: It must define a local array of char The size must be adjustable via define macro. The default size could be 1000.
It must also define a static int n that increments the number of activation records.
It must also define a static long int addr that stores the starting address of the array.
Then it must print the current activation record number, the memory address of the current array, followed by the estimated size of the current activation record as a distance (difference) between the current array address and the array address from the previous activation record.

Comment: Perhaps you have good reason for your interpretation of the assignment, but to me, "addr" reads as a variable name, "long int" as its type, and "static" as its storage class.  I bring this up because `long int` is different from `long int *`.  I also have other, more technical, reasons to think that an integer rather than a pointer is intended there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize a static variable using a local variable, since the initializer has to be a constant (it's actually initialized when the program starts, not when the function is called, just like global static variables).

What you can do is initialize it to `NULL`, and check for this in your code. The first time the function is called it will have this value, and you can reassign it. This new value will be retained across calls, so it won't be updated on subsequent calls.

```
void f1(){
    static int n;
    n++;
    char arr[ARRSIZE];
    static long int *addr = NULL;
    if (addr == NULL) {
        addr = arr;
    }
    printf("Call #%d at %d\n",n,addr);

    if(n<10)
        f1();
}
```

Comment: Additionally, static local variables (but not automatic ones) are subject to default initialization.  For pointers, default initialization produces a null pointer, so if that's what you want anyway then the explicit initializer is optional.

Comment: I know, but I felt it would be clearer to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRSIZE 1000
int main(){
    f1();
    f2();
    f3();
    return 0;
}
void f1(){
    static int n;
    n++;
    char arr[ARRSIZE];
    static long int *addr = NULL;
    addr = arr;
    printf("Call #%d at %d\n",n,addr);

    if(n<10)
        f1();
}
void f2(){

}
void f3(){

}
```

Comment: `%d` is the wrong formatting directive for a pointer.  Use `%p` (or `%ld` for a `long int`, if you happen to change to that).